# Elixir return values

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to use the pipe operator (|>) to pass values from one function to another, but the results of the first function return my output and ":ok", which then effects the input of the followup |> input.

Example:

```
defmodule TestPipe do 
def parse(msg), do: IO.puts "Parsed: #{msg}"
end 


iex> "this is my message" |> Test.parse |> Test.parse
iex> Parsed: this is my message
iex> Parsed: ok
iex> :ok
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, `IO.puts/2` is subtly confusing: although it does *print* the variable you send it, it actually *returns* an `:ok`.  This means it's going to be weird to look at its output.

`IO.inspect/2` might be more what you're after because it not only prints the output, it *returns* the input unchanged, making it handy for inspecting pipelines.

Compare it to your example:

```
defmodule TestPipe do
  def parse(msg), do: IO.inspect(msg, label: "Parsed")
end


iex> "this is my message" |> TestPipe.parse() |> TestPipe.parse()
Parsed: "this is my message"
Parsed: "this is my message"
"this is my message"
```

As Roger mentioned in another answer, the takeaway is that whenever you're dealing with pipes, you have to be extra-aware of the return values -- in particular watch out when a function returns its value wrapped in a tuple because it may not be what the next function expected.

Comment: Indeed `IO.inspect/1` is perfect for this use case. It is worth mentioning the [`tap/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#tap/2) macro as well for more generic use cases where you want to perform a side effect and keep piping on the original value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pattern match here; something like this

```
{:ok, parse} = TestPipe.parse(msg)
```

After this, the `parse` variable will have the result you want, and then you can pipe it to something else:

```
parse |> some_func() |> some_func()
```

Comment: This pattern match raises, because `IO.puts/1` returns `:ok` not a tuple.

Comment: My point was to make him understand how you call function which is returning {:ok, response} in general. and how to pipe them after that.

Comment: If it returns `{:ok, result}`, it might be better piped with `fun() |> elem(1) |> other_calls()`. But nothing in the question had returned `{:ok, result}` tuple.

Comment: Yeah. This is the first I tried answering any question. From now I will give more details. Thanks @AlekseiMatiushkin